# How to connect to remote server through PuTTY and execute local and remote files

Tags: automation, putty, plink

I want to login to a server through PuTTY and execute commands present in a text file in my local system and execute a script file present in the remote system.

```
plink.exe user@host -pw password -m C:\Users\commands.txt
```

Will the above command execute the text file "commands" from the local system  or from the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage):

> -m file   read remote command(s) from file

But perhaps that isn't too clear. When using the parameter `-m`, `plink.exe` reads a *local* command file (`C:\Users\commands.txt` in your example), but the *content* of that file is invoked on the *remote* host.